# What does "put up" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

This context comes from the movie "Ford Vs Ferrari"

"Shelby's been acting very strange. Ford's gonna...**put up** another team with a GT. Some sort of a yampy bloody corporate test or something, I don't know but..."

Does **put up** in this context is..

**"put up"**
6. To provide some amount of money for some purpose: *The company put up half of the money for the new park. The agency put $1,000 up toward the scholarship fund.*(The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs)

..or

**"put up"**
: to arrange (a plot, a scheme, etc.) with others
put up a job to steal the jewels
9: BUILD, ERECT

?

Answer (score 1):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/put_up) has its first meaning as

> **put up**
> **1** Construct or erect something.

So here, Ford is going to construct, or put together, another team.

---

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20up) offers another definition:

> **put up**
> **6** : to make available

Comment: I knew about the definition of "put up" meaning to
 **Construct or erect something.** but I thought it is only used in a literal sense. So you are saying I can use it also metaphorically?

Comment: They did construct a new team – they literally put it together.

Comment: yeah, I know, but the phrasal verb here is put up not put together.

Comment: "put up" ... "construct" ... "put sth together". There is nothing metaphorical about it.

Comment: I tough that you construct or erect things and not people right? You can gather people or assemble. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It was the **team** that was constructed - put together - put up. I don't understand your quibbles: you wanted to know what the sentence means, and I have answered "what does 'put up' mean?"

Comment: quibble-an evasion of the point of an argument by raising irrelevant distinctions or objections(I didn't know what that means). You must understand that I don't do that, only English is my second language and there is simply some small piece of knowledge I'm lacking. I'm definitely not trying to evade anything. I just didn't know that "construct" can be used in this context, that's all. Ok, so you can construct a team, thx:)

Comment: They put up a **team**. That is a thing. I have said what it means: the quibbles are yours: there is a wide variety of use of the word 'put' in English.